# "Constant expression required" error while making a letter to uppercase or lowercase

Tags: java

This method returns true or false for a certain type of String (for example - Y or N (but not always Y and N)). the method should ignore the case of the letter, and if it is Y it should return true or if it is N it should return false.
If it doesn't satisfy Y or N, it prompts the user to enter a valid value(i.e., Y or N) and recall the same method inside that same method.
But when I pass the value and the 2 options inside that method, it gives me "Constant expression required" error

I Tried using Constant values rather than passing Y and N as parameters - It worked
But its always not Y and N, it could be Male or Female too, so to make that code block re-usable I'm trying this method

```
boolean boolHatchedBack = validation.checkTrueFalse(hatchedBack,"N","Y");
boolean boolAC =validation.checkTrueFalse(ac,"Male","Female");

public boolean checkTrueFalse(String value,String opt1,String opt2){

        while (true){

            switch (value) {

                case opt1.toLowerCase():

                case opt1.toUpperCase():

                    return false;

                case opt2.toLowerCase():

                case opt2.toUpperCase():

                    return true;

                default:

                    System.out.print("Invalid Value, Please re-enter(Y/N) : ");

                    String val = input.nextLine();

                    checkTrueFalse(val,opt1,opt2);

            }


        }

}
```

expected results should be the returning of a true or false boolean value to the main method.

Comment: I am not sure that recursive asking for user input here is a good idea, as it may result in endless recursion :) And in fact it violates the principle of separation of responsibilities... As to the error messages you get, you could probably bypass them by moving calls of toUpperCase() outside of switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch case statements should be a value that could be evaluated at compile time.
Your case statement opt1.toLowerCase() is something which could be evaluated only at run time.

Thats why the error "constant-expression-required".
You should  use if statements for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The `case` of switch should be a constant. And as per oracle [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and
>   initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is
>   called a constant variable.

While in your code `opt1` and `opt2` are not constants. That's why you are getting this compilation error. So rather use of **if-elseIf-else** here will be a better option.